# Download file from MS Access 2007 DB (VB.net)

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access, download, attachment

Hi I am creating a windows application using VB.net and I would like to know how I can go about creating a download button so that when the user clicks it, it is able to download the specific attachment from the attachment column in the database.

I have tried to google on how I can go about doing this but unfortunately still, I am not able to find that answer. I appreciate it if someone with experience in this could guide me in the process of coding this function.

Answer (score 0):

Use DAO (Add the reference of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access.Dao.DLL ) to read attachment field from the Ms-Access database.

Sample code:

```
Imports Microsoft.Office.Interop.Access
Public Class Form1
   Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim FileName = "c:\WindowsApplication1\Database1.accdb"

        'Directory location where attachment files will be stored.
        Dim Path = "c:\WindowsApplication1\"

        Dim engine As New Dao.DBEngine
        Dim database As Dao.Database = engine.OpenDatabase(FileName)

        Dim rs As Dao.Recordset = database.OpenRecordset("select MyAttachmentField from  TableName")
        While Not rs.EOF
            Dim rs1 As Dao.Recordset2 = rs.Fields("MyAttachmentField").Value
            While Not rs1.EOF
                Dim fName As String = Path & rs1("FileName").Value
                Dim fld As Dao.Field2 = rs1("FileData")
                'Delete a file if same named file exists
                System.IO.File.Delete(fName)
                fld.SaveToFile(fName)
                rs1.MoveNext()
            End While
         rs.MoveNext()
        End While
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Hi, I'm rather new to this so I don't quite get it. Could you provide some simple codes?

Comment: @Sheryl-AnnLee - Is attachment stored into database as OLE datatype or Text? If it is Text then it has a file path. Which provider - OleDb or ODBC is used?

Comment: I'm using OleDb, and it is an attachment field I don't know if it's a OLE datatype. There are 3 things under that field, the file data file type and file name.

Comment: Open MS-ACCESS database and check the field types - There are Text, Ole Object, Number, Date column type in MS-ACCESS.

Comment: The data type is called Attachment

Comment: At a glance, AVD's code seems fine for attachments ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb258184(v=office.12).aspx ) What errors are you getting @Sheryl-Ann?

Comment: Thanks for the sample code you provided, I'll look into it soon. For now that should help me in retrieving the attachment. However I'm doing it via web service. And Web services cannot return recordsets. I have read some codes on converting the recordsets to XML and then later converting them back however I keep getting an error which says that the database is being used. How should I go about this error?

Comment: also I need to convert the DAO recordset to XML but I'm unable to.